# How do I embed an image that has an # symbol in the file name?

Tags: html

Suppose you have an image called `example#1.png`, how do you embed this image as the source in an image tag?

This is what I've tried, doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="example#1.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace the `#` with its URL Encoded Equivalent.

So, `#` becomes `%23`

[Look Here for More URL Encodings](https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/ExtGuide/ExtApps/URL_encoding.htm)